# How can I upload a new robot to ROS?

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think uploading a new robot to ros? Is it possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81096/how-can-i-upload-a-new-robot-to-ros?/) by [kilic](https://answers.ros.org/users/5284/kilic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-09-19**:
What you mean by uploading a new robot to ROS? What you want to achieve?

**Comment by [kilic](https://answers.ros.org/users/5284/kilic/) on 2013-09-19**:
I am working on a  project using gazebo simulator, I created a robot and using it in gazebo and I am planning to add this robot to gazebo simulator.  like pr2,irobot,kuka youbot,etc..do you have any idea? how to upload the robot to gazebo.....Everone will be able to use this robot by this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! This question seems to be related to Gazebo, not to ROS.
To that end, you can post a link to the contribution on [Gazebo's bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo), or you can check out instructions on how to [submit a pull request](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/contribute-to-bitbucket-projects-using-forks-and-pull-requests/4028).

Also check out the [Gazebo Developer guide](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Developer_guide).
Congrats, good luck, and hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2